# Move div into another div, which is located inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

What's the way to move `#content` into the `#wrapper`?

index.html

```
<iframe id="my-iframe" src="./iframe.html"></iframe>
<div id="content"><p>content</p></div>
```

iframe.html

```
...
<div id="wrapper"></div>
...
```

The desired result:

```
...
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content"><p>content</p></div>
</div>
...
```

Both plain JS and jQuery will be okay, although plain JS is a bit preferably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't alter an `iframe` from a different domain, as that is the purpose of the element (to be unaltered by code on your page).

If you control both pages, you can see here: [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: In other words, if the index page and iframe are from different domains, I cannot move some div from index page to iframe?

Comment: Correct, and that is why iframes are generally used: to avoid tampering